# Need help with a proof that if $xy=0$ then $x=0$ or $y=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove the following statement:
if $xy=0$   then  $x=0$ $or$ $y=0$.

My first idea was to prove the negation of the original problem
if $x\neq0$ and $y\neq0$ then $xy\neq0$
but I still don't know how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: The tags suggest you're in the context of real numbers. I'm guessing you were given a list of axioms. Were you? Please share it.

Comment: To prove it rigorously, show that a contradiction arises when you assume $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$ and $xy = 0$.

Comment: One way to do this is to assume that $xy=0$ and $x\not=0$, and then show that $y=0$.

Comment: you mean "contrapositive", not "negation"

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**: Suppose that $x\ne 0$ and $xy=0.$ Since $x\ne 0,$ then there is a very special real number closely tied to $x$ with regard to multiplication. Check your axioms, and see if you can figure out what it could be. What will this real number allow us to do, since $1y=y$ and $z\cdot 0=0$ for all $z$?

Comment: as the very special real number do you mean the $\frac{1}{x}$???

Comment: @Yossi: Indeed! Can you see what we can do with it? (Bear in mind that we assumed $x\ne 0,$ so what are we *trying* to show?)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $xy=0$ and suppose $x\ne0$ and $y\ne 0$. Then there exists $x^{-1}$ and $y^{-1}$. Now, you should be able to derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Break it up into cases:

### Case 1:  x equals 0.

You are done proof in this case.

### Case 2:  x does not equal 0.

Since x does not equal 0, 1/x exists.

Take equation xy=0 and multiply both sides by 1/x:

(1/x)*xy = (1/x)*0
       .. thus, y=0
So in this case we are also done.

General comments:
Say you have a theorem of the form...
If P then A or B

The way to prove this "directly" (meaning without contradiction) is to split it up into cases either using A or B.

That is if you choose to split it up on cases using A, the cases will be:
1) Assume A true.
...... Boom, we already proved that one of A or B is true (i.e., A).

2) Assume A not true.
.... need to do some work to prove that B is true.

So when you become "pro" you usually don't show case 1), you usually just show the proof of 2), like:

Assume x does not equal 0.
Then 1/x exists, so .... , boom y=0.
Done.

Comment: How do you go from $(1/x)xy = (1/x)0 \implies y = (1/x)0 $ to $y=0$?